# Converting address to coordinates using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinates, openlayers, geocoding, address

Is it possible to convert address to coordinate using OpenLayers 3?

I can to it a bad way by taking address and search it in the `planet_osm_points` table and get `osm_id` and after that search the `osm_id` in `planet_osm_node` table. But this is a bad way. I am pretty sure that `OpenLyers3` have to do it, but can't find anything on web.

Comment: The concept is called geocoding, and a search here will provide you many similar questions. As an alternative to using google, if maybe Pelias geocoder could be a good option: https://github.com/pelias/pelias

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically mention OpenLayers 3, this may not be a duplicate. A quick Google search finds a page of [OpenLayers 3 API Documentation](http://geoadmin.github.io/ol3/apidoc/ga.Map.html). Within ga.Map is an entry for geocode, which states that `geocode(text)` will "Geocode using api.geo.admin.ch", text being a string of course.